# NSURLErrorDomain error -3001

Tags: cocoa, nserror

I'm trying to download a file from the internet, but I get the error `-3001` back. I've been searching through google but the error doesn't appear on any website, so i have no idea what it means.

Can anyone tell me what the error code `"NSURLErrorDomain error -3001"` means?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote an applescript awhile back that can search the header files for error codes. You can find the applescript [here](http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=30109).

I ran that applescript for your error code and got this from the CFNetworkError.h file.

> Error Description:
>   kCFURLErrorCannotOpenFile

Answer (score 6):

There's also a full list of all `NSURL` error codes [here](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003793-CH3g-SW40). It's very handy when you get cryptic error messages from the URL loading system.

Comment: thanks - the applescript did the trick, but the list is useful too :)

Comment: David Schiefer: The documentation also explains what the codes mean, beyond just their names.

Answer (score 2):

The error comes from the fact that `setDestination` expects a full path with a filename:

This is wrong:

```
[fileDl setDestination:@"/Users/ant/ebooks/" allowOverwrite:YES];
```

This is right:

```
[fileDl setDestination:@"/Users/ant/ebooks/file.epub" allowOverwrite:YES];
```

So the explanation is that probably you did something like I did: specify an existing folder where you intended to put the data.

PS: the dash before 3001 prevents Google from returning any results with the request: "NSURLErrorDomain error -3001", it is parsed as: `"NSURLErrorDomain and error and not 3001"`..

Comment: I'm getting this same error, but only on certain machines, not others, and am already specifying a full path including the filename. Any clue what could be a contributing factor? Do spaces in the file path, i.e. `.../Application Support/...` need to be escaped?