# NSURLDownload failing

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsurldownload

I'm trying to download a file in my cocoa app as follows :

```
NSURLRequest *downloadRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:downloadURL]];
NSURLDownload *downloader = [[NSURLDownload alloc] initWithRequest:downloadRequest delegate:self];
```

where `downloadURL` is something like `"https://www.abcd.com/path/to/file/abc.zip"`

But I keep getting the following `NSError` in the `(void)download:(NSURLDownload *)download didFailWithError:(NSError *)error` method :

> Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-3001 "The operation couldn’t be
>   completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -3001.)" UserInfo=0x618000060a80
>   {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://www.abcd.com/path/to/file/abc.zip,
>   NSUnderlyingError=0x618000242010 "The operation couldn’t be completed.
>   (kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error -3001.)",
>   NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://www.abcd.com/path/to/file/abc.zip}

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue.

The `NSURLDownload` object's `setDestination` method needs the not just the directory path (/xx/yy/zz), but also the filename (/xx/yy/zz/abc.zip).

Answer (score 1):

The error you are receiving is [kCFURLErrorCannotOpenFile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943683/nsurlerrordomain-error-3001). You will probably need to capture and deal with the .zip file manually.